# WebException ServerProtocolViolation

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm playing around with trying to get an image from an HTTP server I made, and I get a ServerProtocolViolation error, which I want to get the StatusCode and StatusDescription from, so I can hopefully see why my server thinks my request is wrong. But can anyone give me a hint to why I'm not getting into the if{}?

```
catch(WebException e)
        {
            if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ServerProtocolViolation)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status code: {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Status description: {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
            }
            myStatus = NodeStatus.invalid;
            invalidReason = e.Message;
        }
```

Comment: Please post the code here. Did you debug it? If you don't get into an if-block, it means your condition evaluated to false.

Comment: ...or you're compiling in release mode and it _confuses_ IDE. If possible do debugging in Debug mode.

Comment: @nvoigt Yes, but when I hover over e.Status in debug, it clearly shows it's at WebExceptionStatus.ServerProtocolViolation.